# You cannot define a correlation name 'stock_status' more than once while running reindex after upgrade to 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, reindex

We are getting this error during the reindex process only of catalog_category_product and catalog_product_category. This issue popped up after the upgrade of Magento to 2.4.3 from 2.1.5. Please help me out to resolve this. Thanks